# Old version of node/npm linking against -lstdc++ which is not supported on macOS catalina

Tags: node.js, npm

Using an old version of node (5.x) on macOS catalina, Running npm install on a package tries to install node-gyp, which results in an error.

```
 fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
```

Via other information on SO and github, its evident you can get past this by setting a macOS build target of 10.9 or later:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.9"; npm install
```

Doing so results in a new error:

```
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

indicating that the standard C++ library its trying to use no longer exists on this version of clang. Is there a way to override this so it tries to link against libc++ instead of libstdc++ ? (Updating to a new version of node, etc is not an option)

Comment: Update to the latest version of node.

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved in Node version >= 7.0.